# How to initialized the default value of a Jersey query parameter from properties file

Tags: java, jersey, guice

I'm working on a Jersey/Guice project.

I have a query parameter defined on class level. I used the @DefaultValue annotation till now. But Now I have to take the default value from a properties file. As the value passed to the annotation has to be a constant I can not take it form the property file.

Does anyone knows a Jersey/Guice mechanism to accomplish this task?

Comment: What about Guice AOP or Spring AOP updating the value of your method parameters based on your property file?

Answer (score 1):

you can define a custom annotation which will take property name and then write a InjectionResolver for that annotation which will read the value from property file if that query paramter  is not populated

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a simple solution to this (i.e. adding another annotation and being done with it). But you could define a custom `BeanParam` and replace the injected `QueryParam`s with their appropriate property values there.